# Would God have voiced all of the commandments and statutes if the children of Israel never became terrified in Exodus 20:18-19?

Tags: exodus

God spoke the 10 commandments to Israel (Ex 20:1).  Then:

> Ex 20:18, 19 - When all the people witnessed the thunder and
> lightning, the sounding of the ram’s horn, and the mountain enveloped
> in smoke, they trembled and stood at a distance. “Speak to us yourself
> and we will listen,” they said to Moses. “But do not let God speak to
> us, or we will die.”

The people were frightened and requested for Moses to tell them what God has said. Is there any implication that God would've continued to speak the whole Law to Israel directly if they remained courageous?

Comment: I'm voting to close because I think this question is based on what might have been God's intention if Moses had not requested. What might have been leads to open ended speculation.

Answer (score 1):

The available evidence is that God only spoke the 10 Commandment Law to Israel.  The same thing is recorded 40 years later when the 10 commandment law was repeated:

> Deut 5:22 - The LORD spoke these commandments in a loud voice to your
> whole assembly out of the fire, the cloud, and the deep darkness on
> the mountain; **He added nothing more**. And He wrote them on two
> tablets of stone and gave them to me.

Thus, based on the limited information we have, the entire moral law of the 10 commandments was:

- spoken by God the Israelites
- written on two tables of stone as a permanent record

Given the above statement, it appears that the 10 Commandment Law was complete and entire in itself.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be suggesting that the Israelites' fear prevented God from speaking directly to them, and thus Moses became the intermediary. But this raises a host of questions. If God is omniscient, wouldn't He have known beforehand that the Israelites would be terrified? If God is omnipotent, why could He not have reassured them or communicated His laws in a less frightening manner?

The implication that God might have continued to speak directly to the Israelites if they had 'remained courageous' seems to place the responsibility for this communication breakdown on the people, which seems odd if we're talking about an all-knowing, all-powerful deity. It's a curious narrative that seems designed to justify the need for religious intermediaries, like Moses, who can claim special access to divine intentions and thus exert authority over others.

In essence, this story, like many others in religious texts, seems more about human power dynamics than about divine will or moral guidance.